# Get values of child elements in a Div and put into a list or new div

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get the value of all the child elements of a div when a condition is met and then put them in to a list within a new Div.

The structure of the parent and child elements are as follows:

```
 <div id="measurements">
    <h3> FACIAL BIO</h3>
    <ul>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Distance between Eyes: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar" id="distanceBetweenEyes"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Distance between Ears: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="distanceBetweenEars"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Nose Width: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="noseWidth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Nose Length: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="noseLength"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Mouth Width: </h4>
        <div  class="valueBar" id="mouthWidth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Distance between Chin and Mouth: </h4>
        <div  class="valueBar" id="chinToMouth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Eye Width: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="eyeWidth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Distance between Nose and Mouth: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="noseToMouth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Mouth Height: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="topLipToBottomLip"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Nostril Width: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="nostrilWidth"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Eyebrow Length: </h4>
        <div  class="valueBar" id="eyebrowLength"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Distance Between Eyebrows: </h4>
        <div  class="valueBar" id="distanceBetweenEyebrows"> </div>
      </div>
                      <div class="wrapperBar">
        <h4> Emotion: </h4>
        <div class="valueBar"  id="emotion"> </div>
      </div>
```

What I want is each of the titles which are h4 elements and the corresponding element below it into a new div which I create as soon as a condition is met.

Example:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<ul>
<li> Distance Between Eyes: VALUE_HERE </li> 
<li> Distance Between Ears: VALUE_HERE </li> 
<li> Nose Width: VALUE_HERE </li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to have invalid or incomplete HTML. Invalid because you cannot have div inside ul. Incomplete because you forgot to add closing tag on ul.

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha In my code I do have the closing tag, just missed it when I copied it out. If That is correct I will remove the ul tags, thanks!

abhitalks I am aware I can get the values by getting each element by Id and then getting the innerHtml. However I wanted to know if there was a way to copy all the child elements of "measurements" at once to save me writing excessive amounts of code for what could possibly be a few lines. I'm not the most competent that's why I am looking for better methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use jQuery? If so:

```
$('#measurements h4').each(function() {
    $('#wrapper ul').append('<li>' + $(this).text() + $(this).next().text() + '</li>');
});
```

In pure JavaScript, without jQuery:

```
var h4s = document.querySelectorAll('h4');
var ul = document.querySelector('#wrapper ul');
var h4, val, thisText, valText, finalText, newLi;
for (var i=0; i>h4s.length; i++) {
    h4 = h4s[i];
    val = h4.nextSibling;
    thisText = h4.innerText || h4.textContent;
    valText = val.innerText || val.textContent;
    finalText = thisText + ': ' + valText;
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.hasOwnProperty('innerText') && (newLi.innerText = finalText) || (newLi.textContent = finalText);
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

I haven't tested it but should work. You can debug it.

Comment: I am currently not using JQuery but I appreciate the answer. Would you  mind showing me in JS

Comment: I ended up using you Jquery answer, as it looks a lot neater, however It doesn't seem to be copying the titles and values ?

Comment: Some of your markup in the first block of HTML was wrong. You used a `ul` with no `li`s inside, and you didn't close the `div#measurements`. Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf6U4/)

Comment: As I said earlier I missed out copying the closing div tag, I got it working in my own code now. I also removed the <ul> tag from that area . :)Thanks for the working solution though